# Filtrar números em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte telefone no banco de dados: (45) 9 9874-4700

Há alguma função que eu deixe apenas NÚMEROS? independe de qual caractere tem no meio da tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim. Você pode utilizar a função `preg_replace`. Ela irá utilizar expressões regulares para remover, alterar determinados caracteres.

Exemplo:

```
preg_replace("/\D/", "", "(45) 9 9874-4700");
```

Em expressões regulares, o `\D` significa: Todos os caracteres diferentes de 0 a 9.

Ou seja, selecionamos todos os caracteres que não são números e no segundo parâmetros informamos por qual caracteres devemos trocar (nesse caso por nenhum).

https://regex101.com/r/QnVpJP/1

Comment: Exatamente, obrigado!